# single character arithmetics?

Tags: php

I need to invent my own conversion function because of some encoding issue.
I decided that for now I will create a conversion table for my characters.

I want to know how I can possibly do an operation like the following C code to print out characters 'a' to 'z':

```
char a='a';
for(i=0;i<26;i++){ 
  printf("%c",a);
}
```

How can I do that (incrementing characters value by value) in PHP ?

Comment: Have to tried this? It works exactly the same way in PHP as it does in C. Just increment.

Comment: The [first result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) on Google for "PHP increment character" also explains this in pretty simple terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables containing characters can be incremented in PHP exactly as in C:

```
<?php

for ($i = 'a'; $i < 'z'; ++$i) echo $i;
```

Additionally, PHP allows incrementing of strings:

```
$x = "abc";
echo ++$x; # abd
```

You can also use `range`:

```
echo implode(range('a', 'z')); # abcdef....
```

Finally, you can convert between character and numeric ASCII index via [`chr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) and [`ord`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php). respectively.

Comment: `for ($i = 'a'; $i < 'z'; echo $i++);` ;)

Comment: I specifically need to find the value I need to add to a character to get the hebrew one. I don't know the range or how far I should get. $data = 'î';
for ($i = 0; $i < 127; ++$i) 
echo $data++;

Comment: Are you asking how to add an arbitrary number to a character in PHP? Because none of your code examples seem to imply this. The C example you posted doesn't even do anything. It just prints out "aaaaaaaa..." 26 times. If you're trying to add a number to a character to produce a hebrew equivalent, that doesn't work. You can't do that.

Comment: @Mchl When the novelty wears off, you'll realize how bad that code is.

Comment: @meagar: Agreed. It's useless for actual work, and excellent for showing off ;)